# Handling non-standard row identifier in SNMP reponses

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

I'm querying data from a wide variety of routers, including several Draytek ones.

The Draytek routers give output below when querying `IF-MIB::ifTable` with numeric OID in `snmp-walk`.

```
$ snmpwalk -On -v 2c -c <COMMUNITY> <HOST> .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.1 = INTEGER: 1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.4 = INTEGER: 4
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.5 = INTEGER: 5
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.6 = INTEGER: 6
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.7 = INTEGER: 7
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.8 = INTEGER: 8
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.20.101.1 = INTEGER: 20
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.21.101.1 = INTEGER: 21
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.22.101.1 = INTEGER: 22
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1 = STRING: LAN
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.4 = STRING: VDSL
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.5 = STRING: Resrved
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.6 = STRING:
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.7 = STRING:
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.8 = STRING:
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.20.101.1 = STRING: WAN1
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.21.101.1 = STRING: WAN2
.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.22.101.1 = STRING: LAN_PORT1
(...)
```

Notice how the row identifier on last 3 interfaces is in the `<...>.x.101.1` format, instead of just `<...>.x`. Also notice how `ifIndex` value for those interfaces does not have the `101.1` suffix.

I am extending an existing tool that uses PySNMP (the `pysnmplib` fork, to be precise). PySNMP is not happy at all with the `<...>.x.101.1` format when using `lookupMib=True`.

```
pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError: Excessive instance identifier sub-OIDs left at MibTableRow((1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1), None): 101.1
```

What is the best way to make this work?

The only way I found so far is to use `lookupMib=False` and do MIB resolution on individual rows after the fact, on a truncated `ObjectName[:11]`. It does feel extremely dirty though.

Comment: SNMP agents not compliant to the standards are out of hope. Either you ask the vendors to fix the issues of their devices, or switch to compliant devices, or you have to hack around on your own. That's why the standards are very important in the first place.